# How to set up UBUNTU ONE in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: ubuntu-one, 14.10

I am a ubuntu 14.10 user and i **can not install Ubuntu_one in my PC!**
How i can install it and can set it up into my **Menu bar** also .

Comment: Ubuntu One was shutdown last year but you can find some good alternatives with Linux support such as MEGAsync or Dropbox for example. I've since moved to MEGAsync after Ubuntu One was discontinued and it preforms really well for my uses and also has 50 Gigabytes of standard storage which is much higher than Ubuntu One standard ever was.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu One storage and music service has been shut down by Canonical as it wasn't making any money.

Comment: I can believe that's the reason they shut it down, but do you have any references / support links about the "official reason"?